# How to verify email in firebase auth?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I am using expo client for my app. When I send the email, the verification immediately fails. When I go to the email and verify it, the verification still doesn't work. This is my function:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailID, password)
    .then(async ({
        user
    }) => {
        //console.log(this.state)
        await user.sendEmailVerification().then(async () => {
            user = await firebase.auth().currentUser;

            await user.reload();

            user = await firebase.auth().currentUser;
            if (user.emailVerified) {
                db.collection("Users").add({
                    'firstName': this.state.firstName,
                    'lastName': this.state.lastName,
                    'contact': this.state.contact,
                    'emailID': this.state.emailID,
                    'password': this.state.password,
                    'description': '',
                    'profilePicture': ''
                })
                return alert('Account has been created. You can now login.');
            } else {
                return alert('Failed to verify email!')
            }
        })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        return alert(errorMessage);
    });
```

Can anyone please provide me a solution for this? Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The code in your inner `then` block looks good, but it runs only once: immediately after you sent the verification email.

When you call `sendEmailVerification` that merely sends the email. Only once you click the link in that email will the email address on the profile be set to verify.

So you will need to re-sign in, or call `user.reload()`, *after* clicking the link in order to get the profile with the updated verification status. This means you'll typically run the code that you have in then `then` block:

- When the app regains the focus, as often the user needs to toggle to another app to click the verification link, so when the app regains focus is a good moment to check the verification status again.
- Tell the user to click a button to recheck the verification status.
- Periodically (say every few second) run the check.

You can pick one of these, but also use any combination of them to ensure the verification status gets picked up quickly in your app.

Comment: Lets say i was to check periodically, for every 5 seconds. Wouldn't that be extremly inefficient and expensive (as the most calls were to return not verified but still cost money) ?

Comment: There is no charge for these API calls. But if you think the number of calls is prohibitive, call it less frequently (say with [exponential back-off](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff)), or use the other two options I gave.