# Firebase verify mail listener (onUserChanged for iOS)?

Tags: swift, firebase, email, firebase-authentication, email-verification

Basically i setup an auth process via email and password with firebase. The user, however, has only access to the app with a verified email. Until the mail is verified, he sees a screen telling him to do so.

There is:

```
handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
  // ...
}
```

which is:

> "the recommended way to get the current user"

Sadly this listener does not react to any mail specific actions. This makes me wonder, do i have to constantly call `user.refresh()` ?

Also: after some research i found [this](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/auth#onUserChanged), but could not find an iOS specific function ... if it even exists ?

Answer (score 0):

> do i have to manually call `user.refresh()`?

Yes. Since verifying the user's email address happens outside of your application, the user's profile in your app doesn't automatically get updated. You'll have to wait until the token auto-refreshes (which happens hourly), or you'll have to either explicitly request an update.

Also see:

- [How to verify email in firebase auth?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71009556/209103)
- [Firebase Auth emailVerified doesn't updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73263990/firebase-auth-emailverified-doesnt-updated)
- [Angular firebase email verification false after verify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54592255/angular-firebase-email-verification-false-after-verify) (and more of the questions linked from there)